# Convert a LINQ result into a list and return it to view using AJAX (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET MVC project, when I use Ajax to get a list from action, nothing is returned and I get error in ajax.

This is the code and the question is how can I return `Linq` result from my action to the ajax as a list and read it in ajax

Ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("XXX")',
                    datatype: JSON,
                    data: { 'UF_ID': $("#UF").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#TBL").empty();
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
```

Action code

```
public JsonResult XXX(string UF_ID)
{
    SCHOOLmEntities context = new SCHOOLmEntities();

    List<FRMTR> Lis =new List<FRMTR>();

    var R = from x in context.FRMTRs 
            join y in context.UFs on x.CIN_FRMTR equals y.FRMTR_UF 
            where y.CD_UF == UF_ID 
            select x;

    Lis = R.ToList<FRMTR>();

    return Json(Lis, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I need the returned list in Ajax and read its properties also in ajax

Comment: *"and i get error in ajax"* - What is the error?  Use your browser's debugging tools, specifically the Network tab, to observe the AJAX request and the server's response?  What is that response?

Comment: Name : XXX - Status : 500 - Type : xhr

Comment: 500 = server error, so something wrong in your C# action

Comment: @ADSMB: "500" means anything could have gone wrong on the server-side.  If you're running you ASP.NET app in debug mode then by default it should be returning error messages in the body of the response.  You need to get the error message before you can address it.

Comment: Try with a simpler set eg `var R = from x in context.FRMTRs select x;` - but, as above, should be easy to find the actual error if you debug the server-side

Comment: I use debug  mode and i didn't get any error, also i use break points but no error when debugging

Comment: What @David said, we really need to see the 500 error message, wrap your code in a try catch statement

Comment: @ADSMB: It's possible that the error happens after your method returns, such as during serialization.  Again, use the browser's debugging tools to check the body of the response.

Comment: also bro when i use Try CATCH no error happened, please any help bro and massive thanks for you

Comment: Change your ajax request `error:` to `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); alert("error"); }` to see what error is being reported to jquery

Comment: i use it but i just see 'error'

Comment: @ADSMB: You see an alert saying "error" because *you have programmed an alert to say error*.  We don't want the generic error message that *you wrote*, what we need is the *actual* error message from the server.  If you won't provide it then we can't help you.  Do you know how to get to your browser's debugging tools?

Comment: using F12 ? i think

Comment: when i click on XXX in console i redirected to a page has this exception texte 
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.UF_B533F67900A740BD5A70270F11AD75A683F9AABC839D2AAC319AC2B4AFC23136'

Comment: And now you have your error :)

Comment: XD , please any help to solve it

Comment: @ADSMB: Then there's a circular reference in your object model.  This isn't uncommon.  You can use serialization attributes to tell the serializer to ignore specific properties in your models, or perhaps transform them into a custom view model to return instead.  A Google search on the error message will help you.

Comment: (knew I should have removed the `alert(error)` but *assummed* (stupid, I know) that OP would see the `console.log` and either know where to look or *ask how to see it* - not just see the alert)

Comment: Your `FRMTRs` class has a property of type `UFs` and your `UFs` class has a property of type `FRMTRs` - they each point to each other so can't be serialised as-is.  (and to preempt "why can't they be serialised" ... because you have a circular reference)

Comment: and what the solution to solve this problem and a lot of thanks

Comment: See @David 's comment

Comment: i didn't find anything benif for my issue

Comment: @SebastianInones: thanks for wanting to improve questions here. Just a quick note on your edit - items of software like ASP.NET and formats like AJAX are not themselves code, they are merely proper nouns. Thus, they do not need `inline code formatting` - just get the case correct, and that is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution in my DBCONTEXT :

```
public MyDbContext()   : base("name=MyDbContext"){this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;}
```